# Can I restore my wiped out religion in Civ 5 Gods and Kings?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I eliminated a computer player that had a strong religion (Buddhism). My religion was weak, whereas this other one was taking over the continent quickly. Now that I have him overrun, I want, well wanted, to work on converting cities to mine, but I see now that all of the cities period have his religion! I tried making an Inquisitor just to test, but he is ineffectual at removing Buddhism, being that I can only buy him in Buddhist cities. (Because all of my cities are Buddhist and my religion, Shinto, has been wiped out.

Is there no way to recover your religion in such a situation?

Comment: Take a look at [this related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97282/eradicate-a-religion) - in essence, if you don't have even one city of your old religion, then it appears you have no chance to recover it.

Answer (score 20):

**Yes, you can, but only if it's your religion!**

While Missionaries and Inquisitors always correspond to the majority religion in the city they are produced, Great Prophets will always spread the religion founded by your **Civilization**, rather than the dominant religion of the city they appear in.

Once you have a Great Prophet, you can convert 4 cities back to Shinto (which will also remove the Buudhism) immediately, which should give your holy city some breathing room. Unless you're in a position to immediately contest your (defeated) opponent's religious pressure, however, you will start to lose ground again.

What you may want to do is to save the Great Prophet until have purchased another missionary or too, lest your religion be dominated before you can start cranking out missionaries.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, no, it is impossible to bring a religion back from that level of elimination. However, if you still have control of your religion's Holy City, and you managed to completely isolate it from other religions so that there is no pressure from them, then your religion would restore itself in that city. From there, you would be able to hire the usual missionaries and inquisitors to expand the religion. However, in the end, it would probably not be worth it to do all of this, as you would, at the very least, have to raze some of your cities.

Answer (score 3):

In order to produce a religious unit (ie, prophet, missionary, or inquisitor) of a given religion, you must produce it at a city that follows that particular religion.

If you've gotten to the point where you no longer have control of any city that follows a particular religion, then you're out of luck.

There are a couple of ways I've used in the past to save a religion though:

- If you still control the Holy City for your religion, it gives off some pressure.  However, the pressure from your own nearby cities following an enemy religion are likely overwhelming this pressure.
- Did you manage to convert any nearby city states or other civ cities?  It might be worth it to declare war and take control of a city that follows your religion so you can begin to rebuild.

Finally, you may want to just write your religion off - even if you're not the founder, you can still get bonuses from a religion from the Follower Beliefs.  If the founder is gone, they're not getting any benefits, so there's less incentive to wipe it out.  Likely the time and faith you'd invest in trying to recover your religion would not be worth the effort, if there's a considerable amount of "bad" religion in the world.

Answer (score 1):

I was in this situation. I founded a religion, but before I knew it, all my cities had been converted. The thing that saved me was to save up some faith points and eventually get all the policies in piety. That granted a great prophet, which allowed me to reconvert my holy city. From there I bought more great prophets and reinstalled my religion as the dominant one.

Answer (score -2):

Yep. Just had a similiar situation happen to me, where my long time friend Ethiopia started converting my cities into his religion. At first, i didnt care as i had grand temples and stuff on my holy city so i knew it eventually it woudl regain its pressure and my religion was the world religion. So for the meantime, i went and conquered the central part of the map, as Rome, whilst Ethiopia (unbeknownst to me) set out to do a global world religion domination. After a while, Ethiopia proved too much more of a nuisance than an ally, conquering Japan's cities which left one of my cities in the middle of his expanded kingdoms. So I went out and conquered his cities, liberating Japans' to reduce warmonger penalties, leaving him with only one city left. Feeling proud, with my new truly Roman-like empire, i had my troops return home, my units garissoned and reduce my gold costs as it was a whopping -80 (when i would normally have it at +100), by reestablishing relationships, trade routes and trade deals. Amidst all this, knowing that this is my time to set my Catholicism to spread from the central-east, i tried to purchase a Great prophet. Confused why i couldnt it turned out i couldnt and hAd my religion wiped out except for in my holy city. The followers of the religion were 10-9 with Ethiopia's teengriism the slightly more dominant religion but with insane pressure of 36-20 and so i thought on accepting Teengrism so i checked its relgiious benefits until i saw Ethiopa's religion control, his controlled all of the cities by religion 33-1 except Mongolia's Buddhism. To my shock, i realised all the pressure was caused by the 7 trade routes from all the different Tengriism cities, so to stop this i relocated all my caravans away despite the much reduced income, thinking it wasnt going to be permanent as i still had 3000 gold left after the costs of the war, despite the negative income. Now after finally succesfully waiting and relocating my caravans awawy, i saw that the pressure has significantly reduced to 20-20, from 36-20, but there was still 1 active trade route. From my well established friend, Japan, who's cities surrounded my seaport city where I relocated my caravans to. So to deal with this i sent a huge portion of my units to that city, as defence, declared war to rid my city of thatnlast pressure. Only to leave Rome with pressures of 20-14 which left the follower count stagnant and unchanged even aftern waiting 20 turns. And by warring the only city that still liked me, all of the other nations had denounced me leaving me unable to amend my relations with all of them as they all declared war on me (except China who was recovering from a war with Mongolia) which eventually resulted in me loosing my superpower status from number 1 with pointiest sticks of 6k to the last with 800 (during the modern era). Now, i guess since you have stuck and read this for so long, all i gotta say is, Ethiopia that bastard had the last laugh after all. Leaving Me A Valuable Lesson learnt:F*** Relgion.

Comment: I recommend that you skip anything that drags on the answer for too long. Stick to only necessary information, and make things easier to read for others if you can. Finally, if you have an answer that actually answers the question, I recommend you edit your answer into something that's relevant, or simply remove it if you have no solution to provide. As of now, there's no answer in your post.